# Why doesn't split work on react state variable?

Tags: reactjs, string, typescript

I have a [function](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/newline-in-react-string-solved/68484):

```
  NewlineText(props: any) {
    const text = props.text;
    const newText = text.split('\n');
    console.log(newText);
    return text.split('\n').map( (str: any) => <p>{str}</p>);
  };
```

When I test it:

```
<this.NewlineText text={'Line one\nLine two\nLine three'} />
```

this works fine, as does:

```
const txt= 'Line one\nLine two\nLine three';
<this.NewlineText text={txt} />
```

However, when I try:

```
const txt= this.state.avar;
<this.NewlineText text={txt} />
```

the `/n`s are ignored, and `console.log(newText);` shows the text as a single item. What's up?

(The code to set `avar` is complex but it is a string and its value seems to be correct as per `console.log(newText)` display).

Comment: What *is* the value of `avar`? Is it a string with literal `\n` characters in it? As in `"a\\nb\\nc"`? Or does it perhaps contain `\r` control characters? Or anything else?

Comment: Just normal text plus one `\n` I pasted its value as a literal and it worked then.

Comment: Try `console.log([...this.state.avar]);` and/or `console.log(Array.from(this.state.avar, x => x.charCodeAt(0)));` to verify what characters you actually have in the string. Compare it with a literal string that should be the same and see if there are any differences.

Comment: Are your examples correct here? `const txt= {'Line one\nLine two\nLine three'};` is impossible to construct as JS will just error out as your're trying to create an object with a property of `'Line one\nLine two\nLine three'` with no value so JS will just error...Did you mean `const txt = 'line one\nline two\nline three';`. We also need the value of `this.state.avar` to help efficiently.

Comment: @lovedev yes ta, will amend.

Comment: No worries, could you provide the value of `this.state.avar` or an example close to it, then I can do some debugging on my end.

Comment: @lovedev and @vlaz I tried a 2nd example and it looks like  data: `\n` being translated to `\\n` . Pretty sure the first didn't display the double slashes. Will investigate, ta for help.